# Find which plugins fail to load in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I had a working project built in cordova 2.0.0. Now with new android versions I am not able to get the deviceReady function to be called on some devices. 
What can be the reason for it?
It surely has to do something with the plugins loaded. Some devices might be supporting them and some might not. 
I have used lots of plugins like FB, File, Media, Download etc. I am downloading files and storing in the devices memory.
Can you suggest me a way to debug it to find exactly which plugins are being loaded and which are being not. (I am debugging by connecting the device to chrome inspect device).

Answer (score 0):

Usually plugins create special objects that are used to provide access to their APIs.

To test on device you can use http://jsconsole.com/. After it loads the page you can send remote console commands and check what plugins are missing.

Another option is to debug on Android devices with Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging .